# iOS accessing NSObject class from my viewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

I'm trying to access to another class from my viewcontoller but is not working:

```
viewcontroller.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class firstClass; //nsobject class


@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    firstClass *firstclass;

}

@property (retain,nonatomic) LEMZfirstClass *firstclass;

---
firstClass.h:

#import "LEMZViewController.h"


@interface firstClass : NSObject
{
    ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (retain,nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;


-(void)doSomenthing;


firstClass.m:

@synthesize viewController;


-(void)doSomenthing
{
    viewController.firstclass=self;
    viewController.outPutLabel.text=@"This is my Label";
}



viewcontroller.m:

@synthesize firstclass;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [firstclass doSomenthing];

}
```

it compiles with no errors but the label is never updated and for that matter the first class is never call it all. What I'm doing wrong? I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I'm noticing:

1. Generally you would have the ViewController class handle updating its own UI elements, not another class.
2. Where is your outPutLabel variable? Is it created by code or an IBOutlet that is wired up in InterfaceBuilder?
3. Before you can call something on firstclass, you must create it. Something like this:

   firstclass = [[firstClass alloc] init];
   [firstclass doSomenthing];

The `viewController.firstclass=self;` line would be redundant then.

Answer (score 0):

Your firstClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface firstClass : NSObject
+(NSString *)doSomenthing; //Instance Class
@end
```

firstClass.m

```
 #import "firstClass.h"

@implementation firstClass
+(NSString *)doSomenthing
{

    return @"This is my Label";
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "firstClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    [firstClass doSomenthing];

    outPutLabel.text=[firstClass doSomenthing];;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Note: Here I am using instance class. Before you work this code you must study about Instance class.